# Integrating Play framework 2.0 and Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, playframework-2.0, integration

I have developed a Spring/JPA application: **the service, repository and domain layers are nearing completion**.

The **only layer that is missing is the web layer**. I am considering using Playframework 2.0 for the web layer but I am not sure whether I can **inject/use spring beans in my Playframework 2.0 classes**.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can.  Updated for Play 2.5.x:

https://github.com/remithieblin/play-spring-loader

Comment: By the way how do I install this/a plugin onto Play?

Comment: This plugin will use Spring 4 with Play 2: https://github.com/scott-phillips/Spring4Play2

Answer (score 3):

Alex.p is right there is support for spring in PlayFramework

Have a look here :
http://typesafe.com/blog/announcing-play-framework-21-the-high-velocit

and on example here :
https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo

Cheers

I just tested it on my project it works but on playframework 2.1 in 2.0 it didn't work.

Comment: Please update the [links](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to add clarity

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another way of injecting beans using Spring. Standard annotations are used. No plugin is required.

https://github.com/huntc/play-spring

Answer (score 0):

There's [already support](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/spring) for the Spring IoC container in Play. It's just a matter of editing the application.conf file as mentioned in the linked to article.

Ignore the above see comment: it seems that this was dropped in playframework 2.0.

Comment: It seems that this was dropped in playframework 2.0. The link you provided is only relevant to version 1.x

Comment: Ah I did not know that +1. Guessing it was because it was rewritten in Scala - couldn't find much info about it being dropped though. Do you know if they have any plans of reincorporating it or not? Spring Integration with Play sounds really good.