# Play Framework static methods everywhere

Tags: playframework

So I am just starting to look at the Play Framework and I see that in the examples (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList) that everything seems to be static.  I am one of those people though that believe that statics are not exactly a good thing and if you need a static you should probably be using a singleton.  Can someone more familiar with the play framework please tell what the thought process was around all these static call's versus something more in line with the singleton pattern?  I understand that I can implement any pattern I want after the initial static method call, but it seems to me that something else could have been done here to limit the use of static's.  Again I am looking at the play framework for the first time today so I may be missing something, so feel free to enlighten me.  Thank's.

Comment: duplicate question and answered by Guillaume Bort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192904/play-framework-uses-a-lot-of-statics

Answer (score 3):

Play's approach is to be stateless, whereas non-static methods introduce state to a class.

The Singleton pattern does not really work there, either. With a Singleton, you have exactly *one global* instance of a class. This can have 4 possible outcomes, depending on your definitions (maybe more, but I cannot think of any):

- If your Singleton instance is **stateful** and *global* means *application-wide*, then multiple visitors of the same page will share the same state ("Oh, look, I'm user X now. That's weird.")
- If your Singleton instance is **stateful** and *global* means *per HTTP request*, then you just make a new "Singleton" and do not reuse it, rendering the Singleton pattern (in my opinion) useless.
- If your Singleton instance is **stateless**, then why even bother with generating an instance of it and managing to have exactly one?

The fourth point would be a **stateful** Singleton, where *global* means *per user*. That does in fact result in a neat way to manage user sessions. But it is just not the way Play does it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the stateless singleton statement you make.  I completely agree with utilizing a stateless approach, but I would argue that anytime a developer would want to use an object globally (regardless of global scope) that object should not maintain any state.  obviously this would not be a hard and fast rule, more like a guide line.