# im having trouble justifying the playframework flat and static architecture

Tags: playframework

I'm starting a new project and to some extent are having trouble arguing for plays flat architecture (controllers and model - no service layer and no daos) and the heavy use of static within controllers.

To some extent it is the movement away from standard enterprise patterns proposed/adopted by DDD and fowler. While appreciating the need for a quality architecture I find the lack of 'layers' refreshing.

I've seen Guillaume's answer to the use of 'static' -  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193721/501769] But he does not address the use of DI to enable easy unit testing. I would be interested in hearing some opinions here.

Answer (score 1):

I use service layers and daos in my play 2 application. You can use Guice or any other DIC to inject these dependencies into your controllers. What also bothers me is the static usage of the DB or Cache components. Sure you can overwrite these components during testing or you can wrap the components into a separate layer, but this is always boilerplate code.

Can you provide me a link to Guillaume's answer to the use of 'static'.

Comment: This is probably the referenced post by Guillaume: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193721/77409

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193721/501769 thanks James I think eve linked to the same item

Comment: Some of the friction I've encountered is specifically the ability to inject a mock dao during testing. So that 'real' database is not hit.

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.1 added the ability to use injected controllers.  For an example Spring + Play app, check out:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars/tree/java-spring

Comment: Thanks James, is there any downside to this. And does it take you away from the pure (stateless) controller model?

Comment: No downsides that I'm aware of.  There are places where Spring uses ThreadLocal but it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks James, we are probably going to go the DI route with guice. At least for dao injection.

Comment: And a big thanks for the playframework. Its great! Especially the fast dev loop.