# Play Framework Main Code not getting

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to Java as well as play. I cannot understand this statement : -

```
    public static Result index(){
return ok("Got request " + request() + "!");
}
```

What kind of object is public static Result index() ?
Im guessing index is a method and is returning an object of type Result. But how it is defined outside a containing class as it isn't allowed in Java.
The documentation states this is a Action Method, but again singular methods aren't allowed in Java isnt it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong (and play understanding is pretty limited) index is mapped as part of plays routing configuration

Comment: You are absolutely right that methods can't be created in Java outside of a class (or interface). Last I checked, the Play documentation often misses out things that are assumed to by its authors to be self-evidently required, like imports and class declarations. This is no doubt confusing to Java newbies!

Comment: Yes this was the case, i now looked at it properly in eclipse and it is infact inside a class. Just looking at the documentation foxed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not outside of a class. Play! documentation is full of these code "stubs" which are meant to be part of a larger scheme, but sometimes it gets confusing. If you are new to play! and/or Java, you will find your way around better if you begin working through the supplied examples (At least that was what I did!) and then refer to the documentation.

I haven't heard about singular methods. But note that here index() is a `static` method. This means it's a class level method and does not belong to any concrete instance of that class. If you are interested, here is a discussion about why play! is using static methods:
[Play! framework uses a <lot> of statics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192904/play-framework-uses-a-lot-of-statics)

Answer (score 2):

- This is actually an `Action` basically a java method that processes the request 
  parameters and produce a result to be sent to the client.it returns a
  `play.mvc.Result` value, representing the HTTP response to send to
  the web client
- A controller is nothing more than a class extending `play.mvc.Controller` that groups several action methods like `index()`
- Result denotes the results are defined by `play.mvc.Result` that produce standard HTTP results, such as the ok method

I'm not really sure about what do you mean by *Singular methods*. Simply, `Controller` is the class where we define the *action methods* which processes the request and give back the `Result` object. This is how Play does it!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Don't get confused. All the action methods are defined inside a controller class only in Play!